# "seen" color within the user profile changed in the new layout

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

**Edit #2:**
This has been resolved. Thanks for the good work, Mods.

**Edit:**
It seems to be related to [**this**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284009/supernova-class-is-missing-in-new-design) recently posted meta

---

In the new layout the "seen" line of a person that **recently** visited the site changed from "yelling" orange to a normal black font that merges with all the rest of the text in the profile and thus became a real pain to find. Was that intended or just a bug?

**Old format**

[image]

**New format**

[image]

Comment: Make it big and bold too. Maybe also, it should be green if they were seen in the last say 60 minutes, orange 1 - 24 hours, red if any longer than that. Perhaps also as a bonus, if they haven't been seen in over year then a little tombstone icon is shown next to it.

Comment: @musefan that is very amusing, but as far as I know this feature was present for years, so I guess there was a reason for it. It's not like I'm asking something revolutionary here. Not to mention that the old colors remained, only the color for the first 15 minutes disappeared.

Comment: :) I actually agree with you to be fair, of all the information listed in that section, "last seen time" is pretty much the useful one and is the most common reason I visit profiles. Although you can argue it's not exactly hard to find, it would be nice to have it stand out immediately. I tell you want would be cool. Have a little "online" icon on the "user info" panel. Perhaps a little green circle (as is common with a few social media apps) that appears next to users that have been active in the last 10 minutes (or so)

Comment: Are we having JPEG screenshot party here :) ?

Comment: @Tlama, sorry, Im not aware of a better way of saving snipps :)

Comment: @David For screenshots, PNG.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks, I wasn't aware there is such big difference between the two.

Comment: @David PNG offers decent lossless compression. JPEG has higher compression in principle, but is lossy and in particular it smudges text (see your screenshot). This is often okay but the effect can be exacerbated depending on the screen and the viewing angle. So the general recommendation is to not use JPEG for text-heavy images, or where pixel-perfect rendering is required.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, you are right, it looks much better now.

Comment: Jon Skeet can be seen in different colors, even in UV.

Comment: Jon Skeet's profile picture is always at the head revision, even if nothing noticeable has changed. (Seriously, it's a new portrait with the same shirt and background. How does he do that?!)