# Supernova class is missing in new design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

In the past, these "supernova" questions had a color (`#fe7a15`). `.hot` questions are still orange, but `.supernova` seems to have lost that in the update.

The image is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent

Wow, it happened in this question's comments too. :P It needs to be fixed for both main and meta.

[image]

Comment: Forwarded to design folks; ta

Comment: You're saying the supernova turned into a black hole? That was bound to happen eventually. [status-by-cosmic-design]

Comment: @balpha should be migrated to Space.SE or Physics.SE.

Comment: @MarcGravell Does this mean that we'll probably see a change soon?

Comment: @cybermonkey change is unlikely, as there's no way out of a black hole

Comment: @gnat So you're saying these questions shouldn't be searchable anymore? After all, nothing can escape the black hole. Except Jon Skeet.

Comment: @thegrinner some may argue that Jon Skeet *is* the black hole.

Comment: You forgot the drop shadow on your freehand circles & text.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Give me a screenshot program for Linux that lets me add drop shadows and i'll do it.

Comment: @Scimonster `scrot` is an awesome screenshot program for linux. Use `scrot -s` and click the window. Problem solved

Comment: @Scimonster I misread your comment, try this instead: `scrot 'tmp.png' -s; convert 'tmp.png' \( -background none -fill "#ffffff" \) \( -clone 0 -background black -shadow 20x20+40+40 \) -reverse -background none -layers merge result.png; rm tmp.png`

Comment: @Lindenk Or use built-in screenshot features... (ex. Alt+PrtSc in Unity and GNOME)

Comment: This is duplicating the bug reports in the centralized topic all over again...

Comment: Is this also related to the issue [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283681/seen-color-within-the-user-profile-changed-in-the-new-layout)? (which somehow everyone ignored)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it seems to be the same thing. Mine has a better title though. ;)

Comment: Could you please give more readable images in the future? If your handwriting is that bad with MSPaint, use textboxes please.

Comment: @TylerH Absolutely not. That wouldn't be [freehand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/259693).

Comment: @Scimonster There's a distinction between freehand because it's a meme and wasting space because your freehand is so terrible that it renders the text near-illegible.

Comment: This also breaks the mod stat item using the same class.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles. Oh, and also for finding a UI glitch. But mostly for freehand circles.

Comment: I swear I reported this when the meta "preview" came out. Guess they haven't fixed it yet :(

Comment: Just noticed that this affects the "X characters left" display when posting comments, too. The colors were getting redder, then suddenly everything went black.

Comment: I think we can close this now as this been resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks design team!

[image: bug was fixed]