# Newly upvoted cool comments get an uncolored score

Tags: bug, design

#### Edit

I just brought this up [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253332/238826). Although it isn't a very high priority, hopefully it'll get fixed. This bug is slowly starting to annoy me more and more.

---

I just noticed while upvoting a comment today, that right after it is upvoted, the color of the `cool` comment score became black:

[image: Black vote count on comment]

but, once the page is refreshed, and from then on, it became grey:

[image: Grey vote count on comment]

I also noticed that the HTML for the comment score that was initially upvoted (the non-colored  one) was:

```html
<td class=" comment-score">
    <span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class>1</span>
</td>
```

Whereas the HTML for the comment score after the page was refreshed is:

```html
<td class=" comment-score">
    <span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span>
</td>
```

It looks like it could be something that could have been by design, but, due to the fact that the [Supernova class is missing in new design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284009/supernova-class-is-missing-in-new-design), and because it only happens with `cool` comments, I don't think it's meant. If it is meant, I don't think that it looks very good as-is.

This only happens on `cool` comments, and on both MSO and SO

Comment: looks like a javascript bug to me

Comment: Oh god I'm really color blind. I see both of them dark blue.

Comment: @tbodt lets use jQuery to fix it

Comment: Why couldn't this be by design (to make it more obvious to you what you just voted on)?

Comment: I just run `$('.comment-score span').addClass('hot');` in a user script because I am aroused by comments.

Comment: @Joe: Why does it need to be more obvious what you just voted on? You _just_ voted on it...

Comment: Man, this title "What is a cool comment?" on the Hot Meta Posts board was very misleading

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the bug. Here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
renderScore: function (score) {
    var result = "";
    if (score && score > 0) {
        var css = score < 5 ? '' : score <= 15 ? 'warm' : score <= 30 ? 'hot' : 'supernova';
        result += '<span title="' + "number of 'useful comment' votes received" + '" class="' + css + '">' + score + '</span>';
    }
    this.jComment.find(".comment-score").html(result);
}
```

For some insufficient reason, `'cool'` was replaced by `'` in line 4 of that snippet. The result is that comments with a score of less than 5 end up with a class of `''`, instead of `'cool'`.

My best guess for why this happened is that [someone](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldvwp8uv/1/embedded/result/) removed the class at the request of a blackmailing unicorn.

Comment: FWIW, you can find the [unminified JS code](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js) by changing the hostname from `cnd.sstatic.net` to `cdn-dev.sstatic.net` in the script URL. (Alas, it doesn't work for the chat JS, though.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Edited to include unmagnified code.

Comment: I'm slightly red colorblind and didn't even notice that the colors changed based on votes before!

Comment: I've just added a client-side fix for this bug to the [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) devel branch. It works by listening for comment (un)vote AJAX events (which are how the `renderScore` method gets called) and setting the score class to `cool` if it is empty. Thanks for figuring out where the problem was!