# What is a cool comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was looking at *[Newly upvoted cool comments get an uncolored score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284223)*, because it was trending, and I was just wondering, what *is* a "cool" comment?

What is the deciding algorithm between a useful comment and a cool useful comment?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

It's just the name of one of the classes they used in the CSS. The comments get colored differently at certain levels of upvotes:

**0–4:** "cool" class
**5–15:** "warm" class
**16–30:** "hot" class
**31+:** "supernova" class