# Where to see the status of very first flag?

Tags: bug, flags

Yesterday I flagged one answer as Not an answer first time on my StackOverflowMeta profile. However I'm unable to see status on that flag anywhere. But later it turned to be helpful then it started show in my meta user profile. Is it by design or a bug?

My flag was [there in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284403/what-is-a-cool-comment/284633#284633) but that answer is removed now.

Comment: Possible cross-site [dupe on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159693/all-users-should-see-their-flag-history-as-soon-as-they-make-a-flag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As we can see the flags count if it is 0 also which is not visible previously.

[image]